# Preventing overlap of number ranges

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, numbers, logic

I failed at this problem for several hours now and just can't get my head around it. It seems fairly simple from a "human" POV, but somehow I just can't seem able to write it into code.

Situation: Given several number ranges that are defined by a starting number and the current "active" number which are assigned to specific locations (or 0 for generic ones)

```
startno   | actualno | location
100       | 159      | 0
200       | 203      | 1
300       | 341      | 2
400       | 402      | 0
```

Now, as you can see, there can also be two ranges for one location. In this case, only the range with the highest startno (in this case, 400) is regarded as active, the other one only exists for history purposes.

Every user is assigned to a specific location (the same IDs as in the location column), but never to a generic one (zero).

When a used wants a new number, he will get a number assigned from a range that is assigned to his location, or, if none is found, from the highest generic one (e.g. user.location = 0 would get 403, user.location = 2 would get 342).

Then, the user can select to either use this number or an amount X starting from the assigned number.

Here comes the question: How can I assure that the ranges don't overlap into each other? Say the user (location = 2) gets the next number 342 and decides he needs 100 numbers following that. This would produce the end number to 441, which is inside the generic range, which mustn't happen.

I tried around with several nested SELECTs, using both the starting and ending number, aggregating MAX(), JOINing the table on itself, but I just can't get it 100% right.

Comment: What if range is getting overlap?
means as you told user 2 wants 100 numbers then in this what you want to do?
Do you want to give error or you want to define new renge (in this example 500)?

Comment: It should result in an error. The ranges are manually created somewhere else in the system and are (for a user) static. So, if one range is "full" (e.g. range 300 has the actualno at 399) it should also prevent users from creating new numbers in that range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As so often, I found an approach not long after posting the question. It seems describing a problem so other people understand it is half-way to getting the solution. At least, I got a possible one which so far proofed to be quite resistant.

I query the database with

```
SELECT nostart FROM numbers
WHERE nostart BETWEEN X AND Y
```

where `X` is the start number requested and `Y` is the end number of the user. (To be conform with my introduction example, `X = 342` and `Y = 441`

This will then give me a list of all ranges whose starting number is inside the range of the numbers the user requested, in this case the list would be

```
nostart 
400
```

Now, if the query doesn't find a result, I'm golden and the numbers can be used. If the query finds a single result, and that result is equal to the starting number of the user, I'm also OK because this means it's the first time a user requested something from this range.

If that is not the case, the range cannot be used, because another range is inside it. Also, if the query finds multiple results (e.g. for `X = 100` and `Y = 350`, which would result in `100|200|300` I also deny the request, because several ranges are overlapped.

If anyone has a better solution or notes on this one, I'll leave this here and use it as long as it works out.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding with such a thing I may just create a trigger on the table in db to do the validation and raise an error if overlap found while the application update the table, so that user will just simply get an error saying you can't do it. Say if you want it end with 441 then just let user do it and try to update the table with **actualno** to 441, then a simple select compare the new number to all existing **startno** see if it's bigger than any **startno** then raise the error. Something like following in the update trigger:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM 
         Table1
         WHERE @newnumber >= startno AND id <> @currentID)
BEGIN
    'Go Raise the error
END
```

Well maybe I missed something here in some certain case this won't work and please let me know.

Using trigger for data integrity check is totally OK and shouldn't be a problem at all. This would be much easier than validation ahead especially if you think about multithreading stuff might create some big problem there.

In the other hand, for prevent this happened too easy, I might just add couple more zero into those numbers as initial values:

```
startno   | actualno | location
100000    | 100059   | 0
200000    | 200003   | 1
300000    | 300041   | 2
400000    | 400002   | 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately I can't do anything other than select and update in the database, as it's used by other services and not in my administration. But wouldn't the same check be viable "beforehand" in my application, too?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it, no matter who use this won't eventually lead to the value update in the table? Not adding the check into trigger would lead to some concurrence problem, say if two user tried to do the same thing at same time, each of them want create 50, even you validation pass you might make they overlap to each other with both using 341-391.

Comment: I know, and I'm working on convincing them. Unfortunately, for now I need to do this on the client side, even though I am absolutely aware of the underlying problems this arises.

Comment: wow, then maybe when you pull the data pull the next big number as well to the client side and check if user value bigger than it?